# UILabel setting text resets Label settings from IB

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, uikit, uilabel

I have UILabel placed inside of UIViewController in Storyboard, correctly connected via outlets, everything as usual. This is how it looks like in Interface Builder.

[image: Label in IB]

When I simply run my app it looks like it should.

[image: Label in runtime]

But when I set text programmatically using simple `.text` property, label breaks its style.

[image: Label in runtime resets style]

Whats going on with my label? I don't use custom class or any custom logic except `setText` via property. Why it dismisses IB style after `setText`?

---

upd

Here is complete screenshot of IB attributes

[image: IB attributes]

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `attributedText` is set by your initial configuration, so when you set `text` all of the attributed text information gets removed. Consider taking a mutable copy of the `attributedText` and updating it (or just replacing the `attributedText` with something new).

Comment: That was first I thought about - text attribute is set to "plain"

Comment: Do some logging of the label properties before and after to see what's going on.